# Lock user to more that one IP

Tags: mysql

I have account on MySQL server, which I want to lock to more than one IP. It's because I log to MySQL direct from server and another time from home with diferent IP (not 'localhost').

I need somethink like: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database.* TO 'user'@'first_ip' AND GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database.* TO 'user'@'second_ip'.

Is there any way to have it without two accounts?

Thanks

Comment: not really, unless the ips are close enough that you can wildcard it, e.g. `grant ... to 'user'@'127.0.0.%'` or whatever.

Comment: IPs isn't close at all, sadly, but ... thanks

Comment: If you can set the reverse DNS for both hosts, you could point one to `first_machine.example.com` and the other to `second_machine.example.com` (configuring the corresponding forward records in `example.com` accordingly), then have a single user `'user'@'%.example.com'`.

Comment: Though, to be honest, one more typically sees home users ssh/vpn to the internal network (or in your case, server) and then connect/tunnel to MySQL via that—so MySQL would always see the user connecting from the same host (and never from home).